# Sending DocuSign Envelope via Apex

Tags: apex, docusign

I have seen some code example where dsfs objects are added to Salesforce and DocuSign pickup the data change and create envelopes accordingly.

```
public static void sendDoc(id propertyId){

        Property__c p  = [select id, name, Docusign_Template_Id__c, (select id, name from Leads__r) from Property__c where id=:propertyId];
        dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope__c newEnvelope = new dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope__c();
    newEnvelope.dsfs__Source_Object__c = propertyId;
    newEnvelope.dsfs__DocuSign_Email_Message__c = 'my new message';

    insert newEnvelope;
    System.debug(newEnvelope.id);
    If(!String.isEmpty(newEnvelope.Id)){

        dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Document__c envDoc = new dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Document__c();
        envDoc.dsfs__DocuSign_EnvelopeID__c = newEnvelope.Id;
        envDoc.dsfs__External_Document_Id__c = p.Docusign_Template_Id__c;
        envDoc.dsfs__SFDocument_Type__c = 'DSTemplate';
        envDoc.dsfs__Document_Order__c = 1;
        envDoc.dsfs__Document_Name__c = 'Signup Document';
        insert envDoc;

        list<dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c> signers = new list<dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c>();
        integer index = 1;
        for(Lead l : p.Leads__r){
            dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c signer = new dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_Recipient__c();
            signer.dsfs__DSER_LeadID__c = l.id;
        signer.dsfs__Salesforce_Recipient_Type__c = 'LEAD';
        signer.dsfs__RoleName__c = 'Signer';
        signer.dsfs__DocuSign_Signer_Type__c = 'SIGNER'; //CUSTOMER 1
        signer.dsfs__DocuSign_Recipient_Role__c = 'Signer '+index;
        signer.dsfs__DocuSign_EnvelopeID__c = newEnvelope.Id;
            signers.add(signer);

            index++;
        }

        insert signers;
    }
        update newEnvelope;
}
```

Nothing seems to happen - the records are written into the DB but no callouts or other DS contact looks to be made.

Has anyone got this working and can provide pointers here?

I know I can implement via the REST API but am looking for a quick (dirty?) solution.

Many thanks.